# How to page up or down in `man` of powershell

Tags: powershell, manpage

With command `help` or its alias `man`, we can display the docs of a command in shell. But how to browse it? I found we can go to next line by pressing `<Enter>` or jump by `<p>`, but how to page up?

Comment: Supplement: According to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLzeFHWwOZA&ab_channel=TechJunkie, we can use `<space>` to page down for chunk displayed by `more` function

Comment: Supplement: According to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLzeFHWwOZA&ab_channel=TechJunkie, we can use `<space>` to page down for chunk displayed by `more` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You just scroll with your mouse.***

I know, I know, you come potentially from another platform (where you always want fingers on the keyboard) and want that here.

Well, life often does not give us what we may want.  ***;-}***, so, we have to deal with what is. ***;-}***

Yet, ***in the Windows Terminal using the WinPS or PSCore console***, you just use the hotkeys:

```
Crtl+Shift+up arrow
Crtl+Shift+down arrow
```

It's actually the help files, shortcut listing.

If you feel TLDR regarding the MS PS docs, just as the console for a list:

For example for PSReadLine which is in WinPS and PSCore.

```
Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler | 
Format-Table -Property Key, Function -Autosize
```

Or use Out-GridView to filter what you'd need to learn to use:

```
Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler | 
Out-GridView -Title 'Consolehost Keyboard Shortcuts'
```

The WinPS ISE has a similar command to see all the keyboard shortcuts there as well.

Comment: Ah you are right, after printing more by pressing `Enter` or `p`, what has already printed are not erased. I can just scroll up to view them. And thanks for the shortcuts list.